# Make git init with new branch

Tags: git

I'm working on a ruby on rails project in `RubyMine`, I have the `git flow` plugin installed.

I have an existing repository with a single branch called `master`, create another in my team called `development` and I did `git push`, I changed from master branch to development and now I need to do git init with production in the master branch and next releases in the branch development
When doing the `git init` I get a message from `Initializing rep`o, but this never ends.

what can be the error and how can i do git init with this configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are not getting any error here, just an interactive prompt.

Second, you are running `git flow init`, not `git init`. As per their readme, the init is interactively asking you some questions (ref. https://github.com/nvie/gitflow#initialization).

So I invite you to see thought their documentation what is suggested to know how to go through the init.

Comment: How can I interact with that question?

Comment: It is correct, I have confused myself with git init and git flow init, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I'm a beginner in git, but i believe to do git init one time. In the beginning of project. Then this is no necessary for the future. For more information see the doc of git init : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

Comment: Have you already done *git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"* and *git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"* ?

Comment: When you create the project, do it directly **git init**.

Comment: @FranckMight you are completely right regarding running `git init` at the beginning only. However, in this case, it is a `git flow init` which is ran.